# What is wrong in this kotlin null safety in when?

Tags: kotlin

I'm a kotlin learner day1. I got this code from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html and then modified to test null safety (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)

I've got error every line.
What is wrong in this kotlin null safety in when and how to fix it?

```
fun describe(obj?: Any): String =
    when(obj?) {
        1           -> "one"
        "hello"     -> "greeting"
        is Long     -> "long"
        !is String  -> "not String"
        is null     -> "null"
        else        -> "unknown"
    }


fun main() {
    println(describe(1))
    println(describe("Hello"))
    println(describe(1000L))
    println(describe(2))
    println(describe(null))
    println(describe("other"))
}
```

Comment: You're supposed to put question mark after variable type to denote it's nullable: `fun describe(obj: Any?): ....` and drop `?` in `when`.

Comment: Just a few basic syntax errors. Do the errors you see give you some hints on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question marks to say that something is nullable go on the types, not the variable names.  You also were using `is null`, which is wrong because `null` is a value, not a type.  Here's your code with changes made so that it compiles and runs:

```
fun describe(obj: Any?): String =
    when(obj) {
        1           -> "one"
        "hello"     -> "greeting"
        is Long     -> "long"
        !is String  -> "not String"
        null        -> "null"
        else        -> "unknown"
    }



fun main() {
    println(describe(1))
    println(describe("Hello"))
    println(describe(1000L))
    println(describe(2))
    println(describe(null))
    println(describe("other"))
}
```

Result:

```
one
unknown
long
not String
not String
unknown
```

Seems you want to move your check for `null` higher up so your tests make it that far for a `null` value.  As is, `null` is not a String, so you get "not String" for a `null` value.